# Django Rest Framework - Nested Serializer - Access one attribute from a list

Tags: django-rest-framework

In Dango Rest Framework, how do I write a nested serializer that accesses a single attribute of one item from a related list of items?

For example, using the [models from the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/),

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

How would I write a serializer that would return the album name, the title of the first track, and the title of the last track?

A sample response might be:

```
{
 "album_name": "Kid A",
 "first_track_title": "Everything in its right place",
 "last_track_title": "Motion picture soundtrack"
}
```

Comment: Use [`SerializerMethodField(...)`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: Are you ordering the tracks by their ids?